# Sharepoint 2007 event receiver - debug on development environment locks production

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Sorry for the strange title, but I'm having a hard time finding a good description of the problem, so here it goes.

I've created an event receiver in my projekt and it works fine on my development server and also when I deploy it(via stsadm/wsp) to the production enviroment.
The very stange problem happens when I debug(breakpoint hit) something om my dev. enviroment and somebody add an item to the list that have event reciever attached.
On the production env. the browser just hangs right after selecting new element and it stays this way until my dev. env is no longer debugging.
I can't find any reference between the 2 enviroments and I really don't understand what is happening.
My best guess is that the dev. env. locks the dll that contais the event receiver but how the 2 different enviroments is connected remains a mystery..

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 and visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem.

In a list template that was created on the dev. enviroment and moved to the production server there was a static url pointing to the dev.

For some reason when creating an element there was a request for as jquery.js on the dev and when in debugging mode the IIS was unable to respond.

I fixed this by creating a new list template in the production enviroment.